# Dependency Error in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to install a Gem named spiceweasel (https://github.com/mattray/spiceweasel). When running it I get the following error:

```
$ sudo gem install spiceweasel
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: ridley requires buff-extensions (~> 0.3); buff-config     requires buff-extensions (~> 0.3); varia_model requires buff-extensions (~> 1.0)
```

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a conflict in your dependencies:

- ridley requires buff-extensions (~> 0.3)
- varia_model requires buff-extensions (~> 1.0)

Ie: two gems depends on conflicting versions of a third one ("~>" in Bundler means that another minor version is correct, but not a major one).

What you can do:

- If your project does not require both ridley & varia_model, you may use RVM to create a specific Gemset for it.
- Update ridley (the [newest version](https://rubygems.org/gems/ridley) is also using buff-extension 1.0).

Answer (score 0):

Install the [buff-extensions gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/buff-extensions).  It's currently at version 1.0, which should satisfy all of the other items that have dependencies on it.